# Bash script using sed to delete specific line doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed

I am trying to write a bash script to use sed to delete some lines of a file. The line numbers are stored in another file in reverse order. 
The command I am trying to do is the following:

```
sed -e '{lineNumber}d' ./file.txt
```

This is what I have so far but it's not working

```
while read -r line 
do 
   sed -e "/${line}d" ./file.txt
done < ./lineNum.txt
```

I am getting the following error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated address regex

Comment: so you have a 2nd file that lists the lines that need to be deleted from the first file?

Comment: Thanks. The script is working but it's not deleting the lines. Am I using the sed command wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read -r line; do sed -i "${line} d" ./file.txt; done < ./linenum.txt
```

This works (I think your problem was to use -e); but it's not efficient. It may be better to pass multiple lines at a time to sed, to avoid reading and writing the file once per line. E.g., you could transform linenum.txt into something like "6 d;2 d;1 d;" and then pass it to sed for one scoop processing.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. And thanks for the suggestion to make it more efficient, I will transform the file in that format!

Answer (score 3):

Actually what you did wrong is this

```
sed -e "/${line}d" ./file.txt
```

You see, `sed` has this syntax

```
sed -e "/REGEX/d" ./file.txt
```

which deletes all lines that contains match(es) to `REGEX` pattern. Since you have the first `/`, sed thinks you are trying to use regex matching, hence it's saying `unterminated address regex`.

The minimal fix required is simply removing the offending backslash, i.e.

```
sed -e "${line}d" ./file.txt
```

---

**Aside**: Not a `sed` solution like OP requested, but does what OP wants more efficiently.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {arr[$0]++; next} {if (!arr[FNR]) print }' linenum.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Instead of `{if (!arr[FNR]) print }`, you can write: `!(FNR in arr)`. It's a little neater. HTH.

Comment: Good call. I can even simply use `!arr[FNR]`, but I think `!(FNR in arr)` is better since it doesn't create the element if it didn't exist before.

Answer (score 2):

As long as there aren't outrageously many lines to be deleted and you aren't working on a system with a woefully limited version of `sed` (at one time, `sed` on HP-UX was limited to about 100 commands), then you can use:

```
sed 's/$/d/' linenum.txt | sed -f - file.txt
```

This uses the first `sed` to convert the line numbers into delete commands (note that part of your trouble was a stray unwanted slash) and then tells the second `sed` to read its script from standard input (`-f -`) and apply it to `file.txt`.

The above works with GNU `sed`; it did not work with BSD `sed` on Mac OS X 10.7.5 (`sed: -: No such file or directory`).  Test it before using it on your system.

Of course, if you've got a sufficiently recent version of `bash` (works with `bash` 4.2 but not with 3.2), then you can use 'process substitution' to work around the limitation of `sed`:

```
 sed -f <(sed 's/$/d/' linenum.txt) file.txt
```

If that doesn't work either, you can write the output of the first `sed` command to a file and then use that (temporary) file as the name for the `sed` script.  So, there are lots of ways to do it.  However, anything over 3 processes (two runs of `sed` and one of `rm`) is extravagant.  It's probably not a problem if you only need to do it once, but it could be an issue if you've got to do it many times a minute.

Comment: Just guessing but I think the `sed: -: No such file or directory` problem could also be solved by using `/dev/stdin` instead. Can not try since I am not on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the changes directly using `sed` without using a loop:

```
sed 's/.*/&d/' lineNum.txt | sed -i -f - file.txt
```

Comment: nice oneliner. Based on this, I'd like to also suggest `sed -n '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/{s/.*/&d/;p}' lineNum.txt | sed -i -f - file.txt` to avoid problems with bad formatted lines in lineNum (particularly empty lines which would generate a stripped 'd' and delete all file content)

Comment: @GermanGarcia: Nice catch! But I would expect `sed -n '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/{s/$/d/;p}' lineNum.txt | sed -i -f - file.txt` to be more efficient and (guessing) `sed -n '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/s/$/d/p' lineNum.txt | sed -i -f - file.txt` to do the same with less code. Also just out of curiousity: What would happen if a number starts with leading zeros or if a line contained just zero? Would `[1-9][0-9]*` be more robust?